# How to get a Maven Dependency Convergence Report for "conflicts" between Dependency Management and transitive Dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I search for a way to have a kind of dependency convergence report that list the dependencies that are defined in the `dependency-management` but are referenced by a transitive dependency with a different version.

I know [`maven-project-info-reports-plugin:dependency-convergence`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependency-convergence-mojo.html), but this list only the conflicts between dependencies defined in `dependency` (and the transitive dependency), but as soon as I define that dependency in `dependency-management`, it gets not listed in the report.

I just want to have a report, I do not want to fail the build if such a "conflict" occurs.

---

*Background:*

I have a Maven-Multi-Module project:

- formerly I have not used `depencency-managent`, but I used properties to define the dependency versions in the parent pom and declared the dependency in the `dependency` section of each module, with that property.
- But then I thought, lets follow Maven best practice and declare the dependencies and there version in parent `depencency-managent` and remove the version-tag from the child project `depencency`s.

(formerly) I used the `maven-project-info-reports-plugin:dependency-convergence` report to spot the transitive dependencies with a version conflict. In order to decide that I can "ignore" that conflict or I have to do something to solve it. (Typical I "ignored" the conflicts at bugfix-level (version number delta 0.0.X), but spend more time on conflicts at major- or minor-change level.

But after I moved the dependencies to `depencency-managent`, the `maven-project-info-reports-plugin:dependency-convergence` report is almost empty and does not spot any problems.

Comment: That's interesting. What conclusion do you want to draw from this?

Comment: @JFMeier: I added a "Background" section to my question, hat hopefully explain for what I use/want to use the report.

Answer (score 4):

How about Maven Enforcer Plugin with Extra Enforcer Rules?

Let us create a little conflict between the Selenium version as managed by us and the one used by PhantomJS:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.scrum-master.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency-convergence</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Enforce important build rules -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforcer-rules-error</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <fail>false</fail>
              <skip>false</skip>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>3.2.5</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>enforcer-rules-warning</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <fail>false</fail>
              <skip>false</skip>
              <rules>
                <dependencyConvergence/>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
      <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

The report looks like this (you have to learn to read it):

```
[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9 paths to dependency are:
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.53.0
      +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1
        +-commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.23
        +-commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10

[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1 paths to dependency are:
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.53.0
      +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.23
        +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.23
        +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2
          +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2

[WARNING] 
Dependency convergence error for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.53.0 paths to dependency are:
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.53.0
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9 paths to dependency are:
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.53.0
      +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1
        +-commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.23
        +-commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
, 
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1 paths to dependency are:
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.53.0
      +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.23
        +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.23
        +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2
          +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2
, 
Dependency convergence error for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.53.0 paths to dependency are:
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.53.0
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
and
+-de.scrum-master.stackoverflow:dependency-convergence:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
    +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1
      +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.0.1
        +-org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:3.0.1
]
```

I hope this helps and serves your purpose.

Caveat: I found this [strange little glitch](https://github.com/mojohaus/extra-enforcer-rules/issues/28) which can occur under certain circumstances. But let it not trouble you too much, basically it works nicely.

Comment: Its not a report, but at the moment it is the best solution so far.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If this is not a report, what makes a report for you? HTML? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: With term "report" I mean a Maven-Site-Report https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/configuring-reports.html - for example this one: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/dependency-convergence.html